# writing i/o value in text file using bash script

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I would like to output value in text file uing bash script.I would like to print in following 
format:

```
    Add item1 item2
    Add item3 item4
    Add item5 item6
```

Add is an executable that returns value. I would like to save it in a text file in following format. How would I do it?

```
   add1    add2    add3
   value1  value2  value3
```

value1, value2 and value3 are returned value.

Comment: and what are `add1 add2 add3` related to itemX or Add?

Comment: these are name given to the value returned from first, second and third operation done by Add

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something like

```
# This could probably be written as a loop,
# give more information about the items to add
names=("add1" "add2" "add3")
values=()
values+=( $(Add $item1 $item2) )
values+=( $(Add $item3 $item4) )
values+=( $(Add $item5 $item6) )

# Print each array on a single line, with
# individual items separated by tabs. The subshell
# localizes the change to IFS.
( IFS=$'\t'
  echo "${names[*]}"
  echo "${values[*]}"
)
```